# Is it possible to increments automatically for every build the version

Tags: java, maven

i'm looking for a solution to  increments automatically for every build the version and called the archive by it's name without the version.
for example i have a project nominated  "Example", when i build it i need it example-1.war and for the second build example-2.war and so on taking account that i will always use the project name to run the application ?

Answer (score 0):

You could probably write a script that will look for a previous version, and compile the source with an output that is an incremented version. For example, say example-1 and example-2 existed, the script would find the highest value (2), and compile such that the next output was example-3. I'm not that savvy with scripts, otherwise I would propose this solution.

With that being said, this isn't what I would do. I would use a version control system (Dropbox, GitHub...etc). Specifically with Dropbox, you can edit the code and keep the same naming throughout the project - Project "Example" -> example.war. You can do this because Dropbox allows you to rollback old versions of code, so EVERY TIME you save an updated version to dropbox it will be a newly "incremented" version. An automatic version control system seems much better in my opinion than doing it manually. Furthermore, if you're using an IDE like eclipse or editing via cmd line, you can keep your source in Dropbox so that it won't appear any different on the user end - It would be the same as editing the file locally.

NOTE: I'm suggesting Dropbox because I'm most familiar with it and it's really user friendly. There are a lot of other version/inversion control systems that allow of the same functionality has Dropbox.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there's no support from maven, but you can use a combination of [VCS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control) with [CI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration).

The VCS can give you the rollback capability.

The CI server can give you you build artefact with whatever names you like (including a constant name).

Open source options for each include Git and Jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [maven 3.2.1](http://maven.apache.org/docs/3.2.1/release-notes.html) there you can define a version as property. This can be filled by using a continious integration solution like Jenkins or use the information from your version control (sha1, revision number etc.)